# What is the equivalent shortcut in Visual studio code for Ctrl + D and Ctrl + U in Sublime?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS-code, if I want to find all occurrence of the currently selected word, I can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> command, but what if I just want to add the next occurrence instead of all of the occurrence?

In Sublime, I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select next occurrence, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to select the previous occurrence, but what is the equivalent shortcut in VS-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to `Add Selection To Next Find Match` then use
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- If you want to `Move Last Selection To Next Find Match` then use
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> +<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

  According to docs there's nothing keybinding by default to `select previous occurrence`

P.S. For advanced customization you can open and edit `keybindings.json`:
And there you can assign keyboard shortcut to `select previous occurrence`:
[image]

Comment: Suppose there are three lines in my text, and for each line there is a word "_aha_". If I select the word in the first line, and then hit `Ctrl + D`, all "_aha_" will be selected, but what if I just want to select the first two lines word?

Comment: Wait I'm not sure which VS Code are you using, but in my case and according to official Docs, if I select word and press `Ctrl + D` then "Next Find Match" would be selected

Comment: I am using Visual studio code editor.  My `Ctrl + D` is set to `editor.action.addselectiontonextfindmatch`

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+L` is meant to "Select all occurrences of current selection" and `Ctrl+F2` is meant to "Select all occurrences of current word".

Comment: em... Could you tell me what is your `Ctrl + D` mapping to?  My `Ctrl + D` is set to `editor.action.AddSelectionToNextFindMatch`, maybe I should change my settings of `Ctrl + D`.

Comment: "key": "ctrl+d",                "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch"

Answer (score 3):

You can simply go to `VSCode settings->Keybord Shortcuts` and assign any keybinding to any command.

Eg: Search for `copy line down` command in Keybord Shortcuts-> Double click on Keybinding column press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> do add the Keybinding

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> *in **Visual Studios (Any Edition)** to **copy the line down***

*The equivalent Keyboard Shortcut in **VS Code** IDE to **copy line down** :*
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

*& To **copy line up** :*
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

*To change these shortcuts in **VS Code**
**Check How to :**
 [1. Open Keyboard Shortcuts menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnQSM.png) 
 [2. Find Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcrcq.png)*

***Double Click*** to change them!